# Problem with the LinkVault plugin not finding file above root

Tags: plugins

Anyone had problems with [LinkVault](https://gomasuga.com/software/link-vault-for-craft-cms)?

I’m storing downloads above the web root and using LinkVault to generate links to them. This works locally but on the staging server I get a PHP notice for an undefined variable in `LinkVault_DownloadController.php` on line 26.

Basically it’s getting a 404 because it can’t find the file and that line is trying to log the error message but throwing the notice.

What I don’t understand is that it’s working fine locally and I’ve done exactly the same thing on another site with no issues at all. Same hosting set up too.

Comment: I assume you've tried contacting support@gomasuga.com?

Comment: Actually, thanks for reminding me! I had written an email and neglected to send it!